# Django REST Framework - unittest client failing to resolve hyperlinks relation for POST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this test:

```
class AttributeTest(APITestCase):
def setUp(self):
    user1 = User.objects.create(pk=1, username='pepa', email='ads@asasd.cz', is_active=True, is_staff=True)
    user1.set_password('mypass')
    user1.save()
    self.c1 = Campaign.objects.create(pk=1, owner=user1, project_name='c1')

def test(self):
    campaign_url = 'http://testserver/api/campaigns/{}/'.format(self.c1.pk)
    self.client.login(username='pepa', password='mypass')
    data = {
        "label": "something_here",
        "parent_campaign": campaign_url,
    }
    # campaign clearly exists (created in setUp) and GET retrieve it:
    assert self.client.get(campaign_url).json()['project_name'] == 'c1'
    # I can even try it myself using pdb

    # but this doesn't work - response return 400 Bad Request
    # complaining about the very same hyperlink I can GET above
    response = self.client.post('/api/keys', data, format="json")
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

but when run, it fails with `{'parent_campaign': ['Invalid hyperlink - No URL match.']}`.

When I try using `curl` or browsable API (outside the test environment), everything works as expected.

My serializer corresponding to the `/api/keys`:

```
class AttributeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='api:key-detail')
    parent_campaign = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='api:campaign-detail',
        lookup_field='cid',
        queryset=Campaign.objects.all())

    def _get_user_campaigns(self):
        user = self.context['view'].request.user
        return Campaign.objects.filter(owner=user)

    def get_fields(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = super(AttributeSerializer, self).get_fields(*args, **kwargs)
        fields['parent_campaign'].queryset = self._get_user_campaigns()
        return fields

    class Meta:
        model = Key
        fields = ("id", 'url', "label", 'parent_campaign')
```

Using serializer directly:

```
(Pdb) from api.attribute.serializers import AttributeSerializer
(Pdb) ser = AttributeSerializer(data=data)
(Pdb) ser.is_valid()
True
(Pdb) ser.save()
<Key: Something1 | MAROO | CID: lrvyw93>
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback and relevant code for serializer and model. [mcve]

Comment: You can try to test the serializer directly without using the test client.. That should give a more detailed stack trace. `serializer = AttributeSerializer(data)` and `serializer.save()`. Maybe it has something to do with the custom `get_fields`?

Comment: Hey. Thanks. There seemed to be an error that context didn't necessary had a `view`, but the result is still same. I updated the question about using serializer directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`reversing`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse/#reverse) your **url name** and passing `c1.pk` as a url parameter, not just formatting it into your url:

```
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

campaign_url_name = 'api:campaign-detail'  # Use URL name instead of raw URL path
response = self.client.get(reverse(campaign_url_name, kwargs={'pk': self.c1.pk}))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. reverse is working as expected and returns the campaign: `self.client.get(reverse('api:campaign-detail', kwargs={'cid':self.c2.cid}))` (I use `cid` instead `pk` for campaigns)

Comment: @kotrfa I'm happy that it worked for you. Make sure to accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding - it didn't solved the problem, it's just returning exactly the same thing I hardcoded before

Comment: @kotrfa Oh, haha, you've said it like it solved the problem. I'm sorry this didnt't help. I will try to analyze your issue again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the results of tests had to be somehow cached. I restarted the PC and it worked with exactly the same commit. Solved.